# Ajuda para chamar função

Tags: jquery, google, javascript-eventos

Olá, estou em um projeto de uma tradução de um sistema que na verdade é uma estrutura de diretórios e resolvi usar o Google tradutor pra fazer isso, usando o seguinte bloco de código

```
 <script>
var comboGoogleTradutor = null; //Varialvel global

function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'pt',
        includedLanguages: 'en,es,pt',
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL
    }, 'google_translate_element');

    comboGoogleTradutor = document.getElementById("google_translate_element").querySelector(".goog-te-combo");
}

function changeEvent(el) {
    if (el.fireEvent) {
        el.fireEvent('onchange');
    } else {
        var evObj = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");

        evObj.initEvent("change", false, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    }
}

function trocarIdioma(sigla) {
    if (comboGoogleTradutor) {
        comboGoogleTradutor.value = sigla;
        changeEvent(comboGoogleTradutor);//Dispara a troca
    }
}
</script>
```

Porém quando eu faço a autenticação no sistema, os campos dinâmicos (Lista e derivados) não traduzem automaticamente, somente se eu chamar a tradução novamente em um botão

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei fazer com $document.ready para o código rodar novamente quando a tela e carregada e com um if, se a opção inglês tiver sido selecionada na página passada, mas não consigo. Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 0):

Opa, você já experimentou chamar a sua função no window.load?

'''

```
window.onload = function(){
    console.log('Onload disparado');
}
```

'''

Você pode usar jquery? No jquery você pode usar o $(document).ready()

'''

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('Ready disparado');
});
```

'''

No javascript nativo você pode imitar o evento acima desta maneira também.

'''

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log("DOM completamente carregado e analisado");
});
```

'''
'''

```
for(var i=0; i< 1000000000; i++)
{}
```

'''

Espero ter ajudado.